# How to get data lenght in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

As Title.
For example which include Simplified Chinese characters:

Len(叶123), it will return 4

LenA(叶123), it will return -1

How can I get the actual data length value 5?

Comment: What version of PB? The behaviour you're getting here *seems* to contradict the behaviour you're describing in your array question.

Comment: I solved the problem by using array method.